# Jar Protection other than obfuscation

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, decompiling, java-security

I have a tricky situation where in I would like to protect my jar file which is available in clients machine.

I have a java project and I am using build.xml to generate jar file which is available at Client Machine post installation.

Now I need to protect the code available in jar file which if at all client/s will try to decompile and then see the code base.

I have a dependency like in when client tries to trigger my project using UI, **I will generate java file in server** and then **download this java file at client machine and then compile the java file to get a .class**. The java file which is been downloaded to client machine will **refer to the jar file and its functions inside the jar**.

I am worried if I do code obfuscation using proguard or some other tools, **all the function names gets changed in the jar** and **the java file downloaded will not compile in client machine** due to mismatch in the function calls this java file has and the jar has.

I can't change any of Server side logic which is generating java file and being downloaded to client machine at the runtime.

I wanted any logic by which I wanted to protect the jar file at the clients machine without breaking compilation. Primarily I don't want client to see my code using the jar available in his machine.

Any help highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: You'd have to tell the obfuscator to retain the symbol names that you need to refer to in the Java file.

Comment: Jars are just fancy zip files. Other than obfuscation there isn't much you can do. You should assume that anything on the clients machine isn't secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ProGuard, you are probably interested in [Processing callback methods](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#callback):

> If your application, applet, servlet, library, etc., contains callback
>   methods, which are called from external code (native code,
>   scripts,...), you'll want to preserve them, and probably their classes
>   too. They are just entry points to your code, much like, say, the main
>   method of an application. If they aren't preserved by other -keep
>   options, something like the following option will keep the callback
>   class and method:
>
> ```
> -keep class mypackage.MyCallbackClass {
>     void myCallbackMethod(java.lang.String); }
> ```
>
> This will preserve the given class and method from being removed or renamed.

If there is only a limited amount of methods and classes you want to externally call, you could rename them (minify) on your own before obfuscation takes place; thus, add your own obfuscation/minification only on those methods. Then use this minified names to your Client's program. The rest is up to ProGuard to obfuscate.